# Groupby expanding count - elements changing of group at different time stamps

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a HUGHE DataFrame that looks as follows (this is just an example to illustrate the problem):

```
id       timestamp target_time  interval                                                                   
1        08:00:00  10:20:00     (10-11] 
1        08:30:00  10:21:00     (10-11]
1        09:10:00  11:30:00     (11-12]
2        09:15:00  10:15:00     (10-11]
2        09:35:00  10:11:00     (10-11]
3        09:45:00  11:12:00     (11-12]
...
```

I would like to create a series looking as follows:

```
interval timestamp unique_ids
(10-11]  08:00:00  1
         08:30:00  1
         09:15:00  1
         09:35:00  1
(11-12]  09:10:00  1  
         09:45:00  2
```

The objective is to count, for each time interval, how many unique ids had their corresponding target_time within the interval at their timestamp. Note that the target_time for each id can change at different timestamps. For instance, for the id 1 the interval is (10-11] from 08:00:00 to 08:30:00, but then it changes to (11-12] at 09:10:00. Therefore, at 09:15:00 I do not want to count the id 1 in the resulting Series.

I tried a groupby -> expand -> np.unique approach, but it does not provide the result that I want:

```
df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('interval').id.expanding().apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).shape[0])

interval timestamp unique_ids
(10-11]  08:00:00  1
         08:30:00  1
         09:15:00  2
         09:35:00  2
(11-12]  09:10:00  1  
         09:45:00  2
```

Any hint on how can I approach this problem?  I want to make use of pandas routines as much as possible, in order to reduce computational time, since the length of the DataFrame is 1453076...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does interval `11-12` have count 2 at timestamp `09:45:00`?

Comment: @Erfan because the id 3 , at 9:45, has a target time in the interval 11-12 (see last line of dataframe)

Comment: just use: `df.groupby(['interval','timestamp'])['timestamp'].count()` ??

Comment: @anky_91 `df.groupby(['interval','timestamp'])['timestamp'].count()` would give me the number of unique ids for each interval-timestamp pair, not the Series I am looking for :(